# Symfony 4.0 in "prod" mode doesn't throw exception when key in array does not exist

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, exception, symfony4

I've made application in Symfony 4.0. When I try to access key in array, which does  not exist, in "dev" mode, PHP throws exception as you would expect. But when I switch to "prod" mode, it starts to act strangely.

"dev" mode:

```
$var = $array["key_which_does_not_exist"];
//this throws exception
```

"prod" mode:

```
$var = $array["key_which_does_not_exist"]["another_key_which_does_not_exist"][0]
//in $var is null
```

Comment: Probably no debugging in prod: `new AppKernel('prod', true)`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Can you fill me in, please? Or give me some source, where I can learn more. I am used to C# and I really don't get why accessing non-existing key in array is affected by setting debugging to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected as symfony prod environnement has debugging set to false by default.

In fact, this is PHP's behaviour that is overriden by Symfony. You can override how PHP handles your errors.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Symfony uses this feature to override this behaviour whether if you have debugging activated or not. It is not in prod environment, and it is in dev as you can easily spot your errors

Comment: Can you fill me in, please? Or give me some source, where I can learn more. I am used to C# and I really don't get why accessing non-existing key in array is affected by setting debugging to false.